# Error In Inserting

Tags: mysql, sql

**Invalid SQL: INSERT INTO testimonial_master (customer_name,email_id,phone_no,testimonial,status,date) VALUES ( 'Test', 'Test@test.com', '989889889', 'I'hv block', '0', now() )**

```
   function Insert($POST)
    {
        global $db;
        $sql =  "INSERT INTO ". OBR_MASTER. " (customer_name,email_id,phone_no,obr,status,date,persons,time,min,entrydate) "
            .   " VALUES ( "
            .   " '" . $POST['customer_name'] . "', "
            .   " '" . $POST['email_id'] . "', "
            .   " '" . $POST['phone_no'] . "', "
            .   " '" . $POST['obr'] . "', "
            .   " '0', "
            .   " '" . $POST['date'] . "', "
            .   " '" . $POST['persons'] . "', "
            .   " '" . $POST['time'] . "', "
            .   " '" . $POST['min'] . "', "
            .   " '" . $POST['entrydate'] . "' "

            .   " )"; 
        $db->query($sql);
    }
```

Comment: `'I'hv block'` has an unescaped quote inside.

Answer (score 2):

You have an single quote in one string:

```
, 'I'hv block'
```

You can escape it by 2 single quotes.

```
, 'I''hv block'
```

But the better solution is to use prepared statements.

Comment: Whats is the better solution..can u expalin

Comment: @Niraj7878 google about "prepared statements"and php. I guess php is your programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes are messed up:

```
'I'hv block'
```

That's causing the error...
Besides that, it's quite dangerous to simply insert your POST values into your database...

Answer (score 0):

'I'hv block' is breaking the string, use mysql_real_escape_string function to make them work.

```
mysql_real_escape_string($POST['obr'])
```

That is the parameter responsible for breaking the string, on the safe side use it on all the post parameters.